# PHP Code will only load 6 images

Tags: php

I am working on an image hosting website. I want it to display all the images in a specific folder on the site, i got it kind of working. So far it will only load a max of 6 images. How can i solve this issue?

```
    <?php
        $dirname = "IMGRES/JPG/";
        $images = glob($dirname."*.jpg");
        foreach($images as $image) {
            echo '<img src="'.$image.'" /><br />';
        }
    ?>
```

Comment: If you only have 6 JPG's in that folder, then it has done its job. Any other image files apart from being JPG extension?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out that some images used the file extension `.JPG` not `.jpg`.

**FACEPALM!** Another good example of how case-sensitive programming is!

Comment: You got +2 for a *FACEPALM* ! (BTW: If you want you can accept your own answer, so that the question doesn't lay on the unanswered/unsolved stack)

Comment: In this case it's not programming that makes it case-sensitives, it's due to the operating system the server is running. If you were using a windows host the images would be displayed correct. But it's indeed good practise to make sure all extensions are lower case